# Solve an inequality involving a sum with a parameter

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion, inequalities

Good day.

I am new to Mathematica and I am looking for advice. Is it possible to solve

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{p^k}{k!}>0$$

for $n$ where $p$ is a parameter? When I do

```
Solve[Sum[p^k/k!, {k, 0, n}] > 0, {n}, Integers]
```

I get the following:

```
Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve
```

Is there anything I can do about it or is it impossible to solve?

What I am trying to get is an expression for $n$ which contains $p$ as a parameter or a procedure which finds such an $n$ with the number of steps that can be determined beforehand. Like a `for` loop, not `while`. It seems to me that Mathematica has problems with sums.

Comment: If $p$ is positive, then your sum is always positive. Negative $p$ is a different can of worms…

Comment: The incomplete gamma function doesn't have a closed-form inverse in this case; you'll have to resort to numerics for particular values of `p`.

Comment: There's always brute-force: `Table[If[GammaRegularized[n + 1, p] < 0, n, ##&[]], {n, 100}]`.

Comment: FindInstance[Sum[p^k/k!, {k, 0, n}] > 0, {n, p}, Integers, 5]

Comment: @ValerySaharov maybe you could clarify exactly what you want then, by editing your original question (use the "edit" link right under your question).

Comment: @ValerySaharov To clarify, you mean you want the answer in terms of `p`?

Comment: I believe you got an answer to your question from _Mathematica_ when you got the *Solve::nsmet:* message. AFAIK, there ain't no way _Mathematica_ is going come up the kind of closed-form solution you are demanding.

Comment: Regarding the close-votes, I find the question is perfectly clear. It is not obvious how to solve the given problem, and clearly *Mathematica* cannot do it by itself without some help. But perhaps someone has some good ideas. There are plenty of questions like this. I vote to leave open.

Comment: There isn't a closed form (no explicit way to express $n$ wholly in terms pf $p$), as I have previously said.

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question states that you will be satisfied with an instance of `{p, n}` that satisfies `Sum[p^k/k!, {k, 0, n}] > 0`. Here is a function to find any number of such instances:

```
instances[m_Integer?Positive] := 
  Block[{p, n, k}, 
    FindInstance[Sum[p^k/k!, {k, 0, n}] > 0 && p ∈ Reals && n ∈ Integers, {n, p}, m]]
```

And here are two

```
instances[2]
```

> ```
> {{n -> 168, p -> 11/2}, {n -> 485, p -> 493/10}}
> ```

If this is not answer to your question, we need to know why.

Comment: @ValerySaharov. As a native speaker of English, I find your interpretation of "[f]ind an instance" strange beyond all understanding.

Comment: @ValerySaharov And as you can see, *Mathematica's* interpretation of `FindInstance` seems to reproduce native speakers' understandings. I suggest, you edit the title accordingly (such as "express `n` with `p`" or something like that).